# rsync sending incremental file list, but no back ups?

Tags: macos, backup

I've used rsync to archive my hard drive to an external successfully and now I'd like to use an incremental session to only update files that changed or were added. Putting together what I've found on Google this is my command:

```
 sudo rsync -vaE -S --progress --hard-links --human-readable --force --delete --exclude-from=/Users/sam/.rsync_excludes.txt /Volumes/Solar /Volumes/Flint
```

The output from rsync 3.0.7 is:

sending incremental file list
sent 42 bytes  received 15 bytes  114.00 bytes/sec
total size is 1  speedup is 0.02

And that's it when there should be churning/thrashing of the disks? My source and target seem to be correct. Solar is the source. What have I misunderstood here?, sam

PS: I've made a 10mb .mov file on Solar and the file does not appear on Flint

adding --dry-run and --log-file= to the command yields this:

2013/07/17 13:36:33 [3636] building file list
2013/07/17 13:36:33 [3636] sent 42 bytes  received 15 bytes  114.00 bytes/sec
2013/07/17 13:36:33 [3636] total size is 1  speedup is 0.02 (DRY RUN)

Comment: Do you know for certain that there were more changes than what rsync is reporting between the source and destination? Rsync only transfers deltas when possible, making it a very efficient way to maintain a mirror copy of a drive. Also, have you seen [CarbonCopyCloner](http://www.bombich.com/)? That's a nice UI around rsync that makes it easier to work with.

Comment: Yes, I'm transitioning from SuperDuper, etc as a first step to automating this via CLI. The Flint volume was an archive done a month ago. To be certain, I created a 10mb file on Solar and reran command. Response was 'sent 42 bytes'

Comment: With the `-v` option and `--dry-run`, `rsync` will tell you what it's looking at, what it's comparing for differences, and what it thinks it needs to transfer. Do you not see your new file in that list? Without the full output from `rsync` it's going to be hard to guide you further here.